# CUPS Error log quickly filling up

Tags: linux, postfix

The CUPS error log is quickly filling up. In a few days, it has filled up to 1.8GB.

I need help identifying the reason why the log has filled up so quickly. Here's a snippet of the error log:

```
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] argv[5]="finishings=3 number-up=1 job-uuid=urn:uuid:87f14fd8-e2c1-3c85-660b-2ac816cdd376 job-originating-host-name=localhost time-at-creation=1657840033 time-at-processing=1657840075 time-at-completed=time-at-completed"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d1741429-001"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/www"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/lib64/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@cms10.rockhold.local"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.4.2"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[14]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[15]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[16]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[17]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[18]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[19]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/mzpay1.ppd"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[20]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[21]="CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[22]="DEVICE_URI=lpd://mzpay1/raw?timeout=10"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[23]="PRINTER_INFO=mzpay1"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[24]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[25]="PRINTER=mzpay1"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] envp[26]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/lpd (PID 5903) 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] STATE: +connecting-to-device 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Looking up "mzpay1"...
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Connecting to mzpay1:515 for printer raw 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Connecting to printer...
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] STATE: -connecting-to-device 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Connected to printer...
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Connected to 172.29.51.44:515 (IPv4) (local port 1020)...
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] lpd_command 02 raw 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Sending command string (5 bytes)...
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Reading command status...
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] lpd_command returning 0 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Control file is:
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Hcms10.rockhold.local 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Ppick 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] J_stdin_ 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] ldfA903cms10.macarth 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] UdfA903cms10.macarth 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] N_stdin_ 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] lpd_command 02 95 cfA903cms10.macarth 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Sending command string (26 bytes)...
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Reading command status...
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Set job-printer-state-message to "Remote host did not respond with command status byte after 10 seconds!", current level=WARN 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] lpd_command returning 4 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Backend returned status 1 (failed) 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] Retrying job on same printer.
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] End of messages 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] printer-state=3(idle) 
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] printer-state-message="/usr/lib/cups/backend/lpd failed"
D [15/Jul/2022:09:08:05 +1000] [Job 1741429] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet, CUPS is trying to submit a print job to printer `mzpay1` (IP 172.29.51.44) using the LPD protocol, i.e. connecting to TCP port 515 on the printer.

The printer seems to accept the connection, but does not respond with a command status byte within 10 seconds. So CUPS considers it a failure, and will retry the print job. Maybe the cycle then repeats?

You should investigate why that printer seems to not respond. Is it perhaps busy with another print job that's been sent from some other host?

It has been my experience that some network printers don't work too well if you let multiple hosts send jobs directly to the printer. Also, the LPD protocol specifically seems to have a built-in assumption that the LPD server has plenty of storage space so it can spool any reasonable number of print jobs while the actual printing mechanism is busy.

For many smaller network printers, this is not true: when the printer is printing one job, it won't be able to accept another until the first job is done. But there seems to be no way to say "please hold" in LPD: either the client can start submitting a print job immediately, or not at all. And so, when the printer-acting-as-a-LPD-server is trying to make excuses in the hope that the first job completes soon, the client becomes unhappy.

If that seems to be the problem, try switching to a different network printing protocol if your printer supports one; or make all your client systems sent jobs to one server that has plenty of disk space for the print job spool, and only let that one server to send jobs directly to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to look at the LogLevel option in cupsd.conf see https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016621
I think set to "warn" is enough, mine was set as "debug" and filed 2mb in 30 seconds...!

Comment: The log level is set to ```warn``` but the log is still quickly filling up. I have set the ```LogDebugHistory``` to 5 to slow down errors filling up the logs.

Comment: Note that editing the CUPS configuration file while `cupsd` is running does not work, as `cupsd` will re-write its configuration from memory to disk on exit. The necessary order of operations is 1.) stop cupsd, 2.) edit configuration, 3.) restart cupsd. If you don't do exactly this, your edits will be overwritten.